# generate jar using batch file adding permission attribute

Tags: java, batch-file, permissions, applet, manifest

I hope you can help me out with this one:

I need to add permission attribute to a manifest file, contained within a jar. This jar is generated by a .bat file. Here is the .bat :

```
del *.cer
del *.com
del ReadAheeva.jar
del *.class
javac -classpath "java40.jar" ReadAheeva.java
keytool -delete -alias ReadAheeva -storepass soporte -keypass soporte
keytool -genkey -dname "CN=SISTEMAS MEXICO, OU=SISTEMAS, O=PREMIUM, L=MEXICO, ST=DF, C=CUAJIMALPA" -alias ReadAheeva -validity 3600 -keypass soporte -storepass soporte
jar cvf ReadAheeva.jar *.class
jarsigner -storepass soporte -keypass soporte ReadAheeva.jar ReadAheeva
del *.class
```

what can I add to this code so the Manifest file has all-permision atribute. Also  I cannot modify the Manifest file directly because it is a read-only file (plus I dont think that would work, according the posts I've been reading about this)

I really hope you can help us with this issue, it is something we really need here in my company.

Thanks!!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html

Comment: I would prefer to create jar file using some IDE and then sign it with your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If it is permissions on the file itself... do CACLS /? to learn about the CACLS command.  Do something like:

```
CACLS java40.jar /G Users:C /F /E
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one file called `MANIFEST.MF` file using notepad or other text editor. Its content will be like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Name: Name of your application
```

Now place this `MANIFEST.MF` file in same directory you are generating jar file. Now lets see what you need to change in your `batch(.bat)` file...

```
del *.cer
del *.com
del ReadAheeva.jar
del *.class
javac -classpath "java40.jar" ReadAheeva.java
keytool -delete -alias ReadAheeva -storepass soporte -keypass soporte
keytool -genkey -dname "CN=SISTEMAS MEXICO, OU=SISTEMAS, O=PREMIUM, L=MEXICO, ST=DF, C=CUAJIMALPA" -alias ReadAheeva -validity 3600 -keypass soporte -storepass soporte
jar cvfm MANIFEST.MF ReadAheeva.jar *.class
jarsigner -storepass soporte -keypass soporte ReadAheeva.jar ReadAheeva
del *.class
```

`jar cvfm MANIFEST.MF ReadAheeva.jar *.class` will change in your `.bat` file. Now onward just add attribute in your `MANIFEST.MF` file and it'll be added to your new `.jar` file